# How to add controls to a GridControl in devexpress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

How to add controls(like image,button etc) to a GridControl in devexpress?

Comment: Use the DevExpress kb...there are articles on this. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/

Answer (score 1):

Those controls are called Repository Items. You can add them via GridControl Designer
And assign particular Repository Item to column you want.

[image]

Comment: He asked for asp version not win ver

Answer (score 1):

If you mean ASP.NET ASPxGridView, there are two different solutions:

1) you can use different ASPxGridView columns kinds as it is explained in the [Data Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3700) topic.  However, generally, this only affects data representation when a certain data row is being edited.  In this case, different editors are used for different columns.

2) since this is an ASP.NET grid, it allows a developer to use [Templates](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3718).  This is a very powerful approach which allows you to change the grid's lookandfeel significantly.  Please take a look at the [ASPxGridView demos](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos) and click the "Templates" command in the navigation panel.  You will see some examples of how templates can be used in the ASPxGridView.

Answer (score 0):

If you install `devexpress` you can also see `Demo-Center` for example. (also [online demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/))

> look for **Grid-Columns**

In **Asp** you got these:

[image]